# How to animate div on changing margin using js

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transform, margin

```
div.style.marginLeft="-200px";
```

On click of a button above statement executes but it just changes the margin instantly, but I want that it moves while changing the margin.
So I need a JavaScript solution for that.

Comment: Use HTML classes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can probably solve this with CSS. If you have the margins changing already, try applying a CSS transition to the element.

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;    
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

In this case the "all" is a reference to the property you want to apply the transition to. You could probably use `margin-left`, but `all` will cover pretty much all available transition properties.

Here's more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition